# Sum of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have no idea how to compute the sum of the following series:
$ \sum_{k=b+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{b!}{k!}+\frac{6b!}{k^2}\right) $. Could you help me? I tried even integrals, but I have still nothing.

Comment: Is $6b!$ a way to denote $6(b!)$ or $(6b)!$?

Comment: It's a way to denote $ 6(b!) $.

Comment: So for example, for $b=0$ you have $$\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{k!} + 6 \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{k^2} = e-1+ \pi^2$$ I don't think that for $b \ge 1$ your series has a nice closed form. It will always be something like $$e+\pi^2 - (\mbox{ some positive rational number })$$

Comment: Yes, because it's the formula for $ e+\pi^2 $, but is it possible to get the value without using $ e $ and $ \pi$, for example $ k $ times something, if you know what I mean?

Comment: My main goal is to show that the value of this series is not an integer.

Comment: Well, I just showed you that this is an irrational number. Is it enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

First part:

$$b!\sum_{k=b+1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k!}=b!(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{b} \frac 1 {k!})=b!(e-e\frac{\Gamma(b+1,1)}{\Gamma(b+1)})
$$
where $ \Gamma(b+1,1)$ is the incomplete Gamma function.

Second part:
$$6(b!) \sum_{k=b+1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {k^2}=6(b!)(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1 {k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{b}\frac 1 {k^2})=6(b!)(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H^{(2)}_b)$$

where $H^{(2)}_b$ is the generalized harmonic number.

Answer (score 0):

For a general $b
 $ we have $$\sum_{k=b+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{b!}{k!}+\frac{6b!}{k^{2}}\right)=b!\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{b}\frac{1}{k!}\right)+6b!\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}-\sum_{k=1}^{b}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\right)=
 $$ $$=b!e-e\Gamma\left(b+1,1\right)+6b!\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}-H_{b}^{\left(2\right)}\right)
 $$ where $\Gamma\left(a,x\right)
 $ is the incomplete Gamma function and $H_{n}^{\left(r\right)}
 $ is the generalized harmonic number.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to show that this is not an integer. I will show you that this is not a rational number. Suppose it is rational. Then
$$\sum_{k\ge b+1} \left( \frac{b!}{k!} + 6\frac{b!}{k^2} \right) + \sum_{1\le k\le b} \left( \frac{b!}{k!} + 6\frac{b!}{k^2} \right) = b!(e-1 + \pi^2)$$
would be rational since the second summand is obviously rational.
Multiply everything with $\frac{1}{b!}$ and add $1$.

You just showed that $e+\pi^2$ is rational: a contradiction.

Comment: Technically, whether or not $e+\pi^2$ is irrational or not is still an open problem.